# Magento 2 - GetLastRealOrderId is always returning null

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, checkoutsession

I am trying to get the last order so that I can load the order by increment id but

```
`$this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId()`;
```

is  returning null.

Comment: Can you give some more context where you are using this and why you need it? There is a lot of ways to do this

Comment: This is solved, I deleted and reinstalled magento 2 with sample data.

Comment: after placeOrder the checkoutSession didn't in my case return the orderId, only the quote was available, is this an issue ?

Comment: @medmek I am facing the same issues, after placeOrder, I am not able to fetch the getLastRealOrderId form checkout session, it works sometimes and sometimes it does not

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your block class or helper:

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
protected $_orderFactory;
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
}


// Use this method to get ID    
public function getRealOrderId()
{
    $lastorderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
    return $lastorderId;
}

public function getOrder()
{
    if ($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId()) {
         $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId());
    return $order;
    }
    return false;
}

public function getShippingInfo()
{
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    if($order) {
        $address = $order->getShippingAddress();    

        return $address;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Using this function, you can get the latest order Id. Hope this will help you too.